# how to perform division in timespan

Tags: c#, vb.net, timespan

I have a value in `TimeSpan`, let's say: `tsp1` = 2 hour 5 minutes. 
I have another `TimeSpan` variable which contains a value like: `tsp2` = 0 hours 2 minutes

Please tell me how I can divide `tsp1` by `tsp2` so that I can get the exact number of times `tsp2` divides into `tsp1` and what the remainder is.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably just to take their lengths in ticks, and divide those. For example:

```
long ticks1 = tsp1.Ticks;
long ticks2 = tsp2.Ticks;

long remainder;
long count = Math.DivRem(ticks1, ticks2, out remainder);

TimeSpan remainderSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(remainder);

Console.WriteLine("tsp1/tsp2 = {0}, remainder {1}", count, remainderSpan);
```

Answer (score 8):

a div b:

```
double adivb = (double)a.Ticks/b.Ticks;
```

**edited:**

i found another post on th same topic

[How can I achieve a modulus operation with System.TimeSpan values, without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295751/how-can-i-achieve-a-modulus-operation-with-system-timespan-values-without-loopin)

Answer (score 2):

An `int` will hold enough seconds for ~64 years, so as long as you stay well below that:

```
int count = (int) (tsp1.t.TotalSeconds / tsp2.t.TotalSeconds);
double remainder = tsp1.t.TotalSeconds - (count * tsp2.t.TotalSeconds);
```

And maybe convert the remainder to int as well.