# How to divide time in equal slots in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I want to divide time in equal intervals in C#. Like from 3:00pm to 6:00pm create time intervals with a gap of 45 minutes (e.g, 3:00pm, 3:45pm, 4:30pm .... 6:00pm.
How can I acheive this in C# ?

Comment: This is too hard to answer based on the limited amount of detail provided in the question. There can be several ways to approach this based on your requirements

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property to define your intervals, and then create a series of DateTime objects based on your defined interval. The example below can be run in [LINQpad](https://www.linqpad.net/). Per the documentation, there are 10000000 ticks in one second. With that in mind:

```
var startTS = Convert.ToDateTime("6/17/2018 15:00:00");
var endTS = Convert.ToDateTime("6/17/2018 18:00:00");

long ticksPerSecond = 10000000;
long ticksPerMinute = ticksPerSecond * 60;
long ticksPer45Min = ticksPerMinute * 45;
long startTSInTicks = startTS.Ticks;
long endTsInTicks = endTS.Ticks;

for(long i = startTSInTicks; i <= endTsInTicks; i+=ticksPer45Min)
{
    new DateTime(i).Dump();
}
```

In LINQpad, the output looks like this:

```
6/17/2018 15:00:00
6/17/2018 15:45:00
6/17/2018 16:30:00
6/17/2018 17:15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

[Datetime.AddMinutes(double value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) should do what you are looking for. Just keep on adding until the result of the addition goes over the maximum date/time you have.

**NOTE**: This assumes you *know* your interval. If, on the other hand, you require to split a time span in a equal *n* parts you would require a different approach, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302610/how-to-perform-division-in-timespan).

Comment: Kindly mention that approach also, which split a time span in a equal n parts.

Comment: @user2176764: I have modified my answer (check the link at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Parse("3:0:0");//If pm it should be 15
        DateTime EndTime = DateTime.Parse("6:0:0");//If pm it should be 18
        while (StartTime!=EndTime)
        {
            double minuts = +45;
            StartTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(minuts);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just be careful since this assumes that the time interval will eventually lead to an exact match to `endTime`. Should this not be the case, the loop will keep going forever.